# How to write existing excel (*.xlsx) file on different column using POI in Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Dear all member here!!

I got a problem that need to ask your help. I already have an excel file (sample.xlsx). I need  to use java code for appending my old data.

Here is my specifications:

1. My old data is in column A, 100 rows for example.
2. Need to write other data (50 rows) in different column, column B for example.
3. Appending data is also start from first row as the old data.

Is it possible to do that in POI?

Comment: @Sankumarsingh, can you tell me a little bit?

Comment: Its quite simple... You just need not to create rows, but just create a new column on each rows. For help you can see here... http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells

Comment: Excuse me!! In case I don't create new rows, the code complain that "Differencing null Pointer". After I run the code, the main function return null error exception. Here is my used code:

`FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null; 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sample_sheet_name"); 
XSSFRow rows = null;   
rows.createCell(5).setCellValue("Creation Date: "+ new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));`

Comment: Be clear... if your sheet is existing as you told in question, you are not supposed to create new sheet as you have done ... `workbook.createSheet("sample_sheet_name");` There are many more mistakes in your code... I suggest...Do your homework first...

Comment: Ok, I understand. However, suppose I already fix this code `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filexlsx);XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sample");`, what should I do next?

Comment: Share your code in Question... not in comment...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sample");
for(int i=0; i<numberOfRowsToWriteDataIn; i++) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
   row.createCell(5).setCellValue("Creation Date: "+ new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));
}
```

Hope that helps.